# How to determine the distance between where Earth and Mars are two specific dates?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mars, earth

How would I find the solar-system-relative distance between where Earth would be on 2106/8/16 and where Mars would be on 2106/10/16, or any combination of dates.
[image]
Image source-[Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=mars%20earth&search=&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=mars%20earth&sc=8-10&qs=n&sk=&cvid=3583FA8A1AF546F887C22F5D2BC8C551.)

Is there software that is accessible, and understandable, by the general public that would allow for this calculation?

Comment: Scott Manly has several videos using Universe Sandbox [1](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16395/7982), [2](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26803/7982) but that may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. With flexible position of Mars, distance travelled depends on the excentricity of the orbit. Just saying it is "retrograde" doesn't give enough information to make calculations.

Comment: If your spacecraft is so powerful that it can inject itself into an arbitrary retrograde hyperbolic orbit, then you more or less get to choose how far you're going to travel, surely?

Comment: @StarfishPrime I think the question is asking for how to calculate the transit time for a given trajectory. The ship has a lot of power but it's not equipped with voice control "Siriexa, go to Mars as fast as you can."

Comment: OP, is what you want the solar-system-relative distance between where Earth would be on 2020/12/28 and where Mars would be on 2021/2/28, or the actual arc-length of an orbit section that hits those two points at the required times?  The former calculation is definitely the easier one to do (for sufficiently complicated values of "easy"), though I'm unaware of any particular software that gives either as a readout..

Comment: @notovny How would I find the solar-system-relative distance between where Earth would be on 2020/12/28 and where Mars would be on 2021/2/28, or any combination of dates.

Comment: The revised question seems to be a pure astronomy question.

Comment: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/where-can-i-find-visualize-p might be a starting point

Comment: I can post a helpful answer using python but it won't help if you don't have access to python. Can you use it a little, or are willing to learn, or can you find someone who can help you run it?

Comment: The straight-line distance will drop out of any simple  solar-system modelling software.  Certainly realistic predictive path distances (as function of max achievable speed and so on) are a massive math calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can use SPICE and JPL data. https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/planets/

JPL publishes SPICE kernels of planetery ephemerides for these types of calculations. This plot is just for years 2040-2050, but their DE441 kernel has data all the way to year 17191. You can calculate the position and velocity vectors of Earth and Mars at any date.

Here is the Python script used to create this plot:

```
'''
Plot Earth-Mars relative distance for years 2040-2050
'''

# AWP libraries
import spice_data  as sd
import spice_tools as st

# 3rd party libraries
import spiceypy as spice
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use( 'dark_background' )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spice.furnsh( sd.leapseconds_kernel )
    spice.furnsh( sd.de432s_kernel  )

    et0   = spice.str2et( '2040-01-01' )
    et1   = spice.str2et( '2050-01-01' )
    ets   = np.arange( et0, et1, 50000 )
    rs    = st.calc_ephemeris( 399, ets, 'J2000', 4 )[ :, :3 ]
    dists = np.linalg.norm( rs, axis = 1 ) / 149.6e6
    ts    = ( ets - et0 ) / ( 3600 * 24 * 365.0 ) + 2040.0

    plt.figure( figsize = ( 12, 8 ) )
    plt.plot( ts, dists, 'm' )
    plt.xlabel( 'Time (years)' )
    plt.ylabel( 'Earth-Mars Relative Distance (AU)' )
    plt.title( 'Earth-Mars Relative Distance 2040-2050' )
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

And the AWP Python library can be found here: https://github.com/alfonsogonzalez/AWP

Answer (score 1):

[Stellarium](https://stellarium.org/) is a general planetarium program which is available for Linux, MacOS X and Windows and is pretty easy to use. Moving the mouse to the left side of the screen pops out options to change the date/time and to search for an object. I set the time to 2106-10-16 and searched for 'Mars' and got the following screenshot:
[image: Stellarium screenshot showing info for Mars]
Included in the admittedly large set of numbers is *Distance: 2.111 AU (315.797 M km)* so Mars was 2.111 astronomical units (1 au is the average Earth-Sun distance, approx. 150 million km) or 315.8 million km or 196 million miles from the Earth on that date and time.

Comment: The OP wants the distance between the position of one planet on date A, and the position of the other planet on date B. Not on the same date.

Comment: That gives me the distance between the two planets on on particular date.  Not the distance between where Earth was on 2106-8-16 and where Mars would be on 2106-10-16.

Comment: In that case, set Stellarium to 2106-8-16, record Earth's distance from the Sun, set to 2106-10-16, record Mars's distance from the Sun and subtract ?